Fetching LOB as String
trying to make a query against a view that returns a CLOB field
that CLOB is a json that i would like to access
due to nature of architecture i would like to avoid streaming
import * as oracleDB from 'oracledb';

oracleDB.fetchAsString = [ oracleDB.CLOB ];

const connection = await oracleDB.getConnection({
                user: process.env.ORACLE_USER,
                password: process.env.ORACLE_PW,
                connectString: process.env.ORACLE_HOST
            });

const result = await connection.execute(queryString);
await connection.close();

this is what i have found in the oracle docs
it seems to not work however as there are 2 problems


oracleDB.fetchAsString = [ oracleDB.CLOB ];

is not possible (without ugly override) as fetchAsString is flagged as read only

even then i still get LOB


there is a second option found in the docs
const result = await connection.execute(
    `SELECT c FROM mylobs WHERE id = 1`,
    [], // no binds
    { fetchInfo: {"C": {type: oracledb.STRING}} }
);

this is not possible as well as type is expecting number and STRING is an object
EDIT: I made it work by using the fetchinfo method and adding // @ts-ignore // eslint-disable-next-line prettier/prettier to the code to statisfy both, the typemismatch for the execute function and eslint trying to remove "" from the column name

To fetch a CLOB field as a string in OracleDB without streaming, you can use the fetchInfo option in the execute() method. However, there seems to be a misunderstanding about the usage.

where is the misunderstanding?
i replace the "C" with my column name. But my IDE is giving the error, that there is a type mismatch
EDIT:
I made it work by using the fetchinfo method and adding
// @ts-ignore
// eslint-disable-next-line prettier/prettier
to the code to statisfy both, the typemismatch for the execute function and eslint trying to remove "" from the column name
